# Protect Credentials on Web Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, encryption, cryptography

I have a situation that seemingly should not be complex but I can not identify a way that meets the safety standards of company that i work.

In a C # desktop application:
The user starts the application stating their credentials on the login screen.

The developer encrypts those credentials and keeps them in memory throughout the application processing.

If necessary to use the credentials for some other operation the credentials are decrypted and this it perfectly meets the company's safety standards.

In an ASP.NET web application

The user starts the application stating their credentials on the login screen.

And now comes the question ...

How is it possible to store in memory the credentials of a web application
similarly as in a desktop application ?

Remembering that this web application server uses clusters.

It is not just HASH the password.The application will need to know the password of the logged in user.

The following options have been ruled out by the company's safety standards

1 - Encrypted in Cookie

2 - Encrypted in the database

3 - Encrypted in Ini files

Comment: If keeping the password on the server, use SecureString. If keeping it on the client, you should switch to OAuth or an SSO architecture.

Comment: There's a reason this not done -- keeping credentials around in a retrievable state can expose all your users to compromised accounts -- this is the exact use case for SSO.  Only tokens are passed around and the original credentials only live long enough to create them.

Comment: So you need to keep credentials temporarily in memory on the server such that the server can use other services with these credentials? Supposing you had two webservers behind a load balancer? How would that work? Creating stateful web servers always comes back to bite you. I would suggest holding the credentials at the client and sending them on-demand. No significant (additional) security risk as the client (by design) must be exposed to the raw passwords anyway. The real problem here is using passwords in the first place. Oauth answers this problem in a far safer fashion.

Comment: As an aside, this might be better placed at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you provide some context? *Why* you need to hold raw passwords?

Comment: Because at a certain point i will need to login into a "acess control system" from my application using the same credentials.